# Is it possible to use another's app merchant id for Apple Pay?

Tags: ios, certificate, reverse-engineering, applepay

The question:

**Is there any way to make app B generate tokens with app A merchant id which will fully work then and pass A's backend validations?**

My circumstances:

3rd-party App **A**:

- This app uses Apple Pay and generates one-time [payment tokens](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PaymentTokenJSON/PaymentTokenJSON.html) which are then sent to their backend server and validated.
- I do not have the source code of the app **A**
- I also do not have private keys of their Apple Pay merchant profile
- I **do have** their merchant ID string and anything else I can get from the IPA file

My own App **B**:

- This is just my app, I can do anything

Comment: You say it doesn't ruin the security of ApplePay, but if you walked in to a physical store and just started processing credit card transactions on their terminal, do you think they would let you?  I would assume that Apple wouldn't let you register a merchant ID that was already registered by another developer and since you can't add the merchant Id to your account, you can't get the app signed as the entitlements would not be correct

Comment: @Paulw11, I see, but I don't need to actually process payments. I just need to get generated tokens, which will be used in the same "store" later.

Comment: It doesn't matter, a payment token *would* let you submit payments. Apple won't sign payment requests from your app with another developer's certificate (in fact they won't let you submit an app with another developer's merchant id) so you can't even attempt to submit a payment request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this were possible, Apple Pay would be pointless. So, no.

Comment: It doesn't ruin the security of Apple Pay in any way, so even if it's really impossible, it's not as obvious as you think.

Comment: It seems as though you're asking if you can use another app's merchant ID to generate payment tokens and process payments.

Comment: Nope, I don't need to process payments. These tokens will be used on the app A backend. Now I use HTTP Sniffer to collect tokens generated by the app and then use these tokens, but it's a bit inconvenient. If you have some spare time and can offer me any way to contact you directly, I'll explain it much faster in Russian. Thanks.